# How to achieve very responsive mouse input in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, camera, lag

```
 private void Update()
 {
     yaw += horizontalSensitivity * Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
     pitch -= verticalSensitivity * Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") ;

     if (pitch < -pitchCap) { pitch = -1 * pitchCap; }
     if (pitch > pitchCap) { pitch = pitchCap; }

     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
 }
```

This is the code I am using to update the camera's rotation in my project. This works just as intended, but I have noticed a particularly small latency. I could *feel* the camera rotation lagging just a bit when I move my mouse.

In other, bigger games, I can feel my mouse movement quickly impacting my camera's rotation-- everything feels very responsive. However, with this setup, I can't say I feel the same. There is some input lag.

How can I reduce this lag and produce a more responsive mouse movement script?

Comment: Are you trying to archive the FPS effect with the mouse?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

You have to smooth out the values from the mouse. You can do that by changing `Input.GetAxisRaw` to `Input.GetAxis`. Also multiple it with `Time.deltaTime` to keep it the-same on all platforms.

---

If this does not fix your issue then just modify the `localEulerAngles` angle instead of `transform.rotation` which is a `Quaternion`. See the example below which also limits the y-axis rotation since you're making FPS controller:

```
public float xMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;
public float yMoveThreshold = 1000.0f;

public float yMaxLimit = 45.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -45.0f;


float yRotCounter = 0.0f;
float xRotCounter = 0.0f;

Transform mainCam;

void Start()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main.transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    xRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * yMoveThreshold * Time.deltaTime;
    yRotCounter = Mathf.Clamp(yRotCounter, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
    //xRotCounter = xRotCounter % 360;//Optional
    mainCam.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-yRotCounter, xRotCounter, 0);
}
```

Comment: Even with these changes, I still feel the sleight lag. Thanks though. And how does localEulerAngles differ from using transform.rotation?